# JavaScript Accordion - Disable closing the panel

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, accordion

I have an accordion based on JavaScript and CSS. When the user clicks on a panel, it opens and the header gets a different color. When the user clicks on another panel, the panel selected before is closed and the new one opened.

What I don't want is the user to be able and close the active panel. This is because the header color does not change back and I also change the color of features on the map. If it cannot be disabled, is there a way to access the closed panel so that I can change back the color of the header?

I tried to make a JS fiddle, but I cannot integrate my code, this does not work. The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0y639ra/6/

This is my code:

JavaScript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-panel');

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) 
{
(function(index){
    acc[i].onclick = function()
    {           
        var setClasses = !this.classList.contains("active");
        setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
        setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

        if (setClasses){
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        }

        var myIndex = index + 1;
        console.log("INDEX " + myIndex);

        //set the style of the route
        routes.setStyle(style_routes);
        routes.getLayer(myIndex).setStyle(style_routeClicked).bringToFront();

        //zoom to the selected feature
        map.fitBounds(routes.getLayer(myIndex).getBounds(),{padding:[200,200]});

        }
    })(i);
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName){
for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++){
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
    }
}
```

The CSS:

```
button.accordion {
        margin-left: -10px;
        background-color: white;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 110%;
        text-align: left;
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        outline: none;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

button.accordion {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #426334;
    color: white;
}

button.accordion:focus {
    background-color: #426334;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.accordion-panel {
    padding: 0 0px;
    background-color: none;
    display: none;
}

div.accordion-panel.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different solutions to that question. While it is quite hard to answer without an usable sample... could you include an jsfiddle link?

One solution would be your requested behavior (user can not close open panel). To achive this you can just check if the active class of the clicked element is already set and only if not you will execute all the other functions you implemented. (Move everything to your if(setClasses){})

The other solution would be to just search for each header having the "active" class before setting the new one this way you can find the index, if you really need it. A better way in my opinion would be to have an identifyer on each trigger which you can use to identify the corresponding elements (e.g. a data-index="XX")

Comment: I'm sorry in your fiddle the accordion does not work as you described (all panels can be opend at the same time, and the color of the header does not stay the same if one closes a panel)
Could you try to clarify what is the current status an what is your goal?

I just saw you wrote that you couldn't include your code.
I'll have a quick look.

Comment: If I understood you correctly if the user clicks on an active element nothing should happen (solution 1) to have this you just have to move the code in your already existing if => see answer update

Comment: It worked perfectly fine to move the code into the if statement. Thanks a lot!